# Approximating a Discrete Function with a Polynomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, approximation-theory

Consider a discrete function $f : \{x_1,\dots,x_n\} \to [a,b]$ that, for some $\omega>0$, satisfies

$$\max_i |f_i-f_{i-1}| \le \omega. \tag1$$

Let $q$ be the polynomial of order $m<n$ that, for some $p$, approximates the function $f$ by minimizing

$$D_p\equiv||f-q||_p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|f(i) - q(i)|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

> Is there a sharp or a "relatively tight" upper bound to $D_p$ that does not depend on the values of $f$?

---

I thought that this would be easy to find online but all approximation results I could find (like [Jackson's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson%27s_inequality)) are for continuous functions. One would think that tighter bounds could be established for discrete functions, but I haven't been able to find one. Any suggestion in this direction would be very welcome.

---

**Edit based on the comments by @Ian**

Let $X$ be a matrix with elements $X_{ij}=x_i^j$, for $i=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $j=\{0,\dots,m\}$, and let $y=[f_1,\dots,f_n]^T$. Then, for $p=2$ it follows from the least squares formula that
$$D_2=||(I_n-X(X^T X)^{-1}X^T)y||_2.$$
It would also follow that, for all $p$
$$D_p\leq ||(I_n-X(X^T X)^{-1}X^T)y||_p.$$
So, one way to get a relatively tight bound (I haven't figure out how to formalize this) would be to use condition $(1)$ to bound $D_2$.

Comment: Say the domain is $\{ x_0,x_1,...,x_{n-1} \}$ $P_{ij}=x_i^j$ for $i=0,1,...n-1,j=0,1,...,m$, then you want the operator $p$ norm of $I_n-P(P^T P)^{-1} P^T$. For $p=1$ or $p=\infty$ this can be computed directly, for $p=2$ it can be obtained from the SVD of $P$.

Comment: Thank you for this. Is the norm of this projection matrix equal to $D$ then? Does this mean that the solution to the minimization problem is independent of the $p$ norm being used? Would you mind elaborating a bit in an answer?

Comment: It still depends on $p$. My point here is that you should probably not expect $D$ to have a nice expression. Even an error bound will have some substance to it; try writing out the formula for $m=1$ to see some of this subtlety.

Comment: Also my mistake, my original statement actually only applies for $p=2$, where you can use least squares. Otherwise the minimization itself is a nonlinear problem.

Comment: I see, then $D\leq ||I_n-P(P^T P)^{-1}P^T||_p$ with equality if $p=2$. Right?

Comment: I suppose that is right, actually, since you can always use least squares as a (perhaps bad) guess to the more general optimization problem. You can get a feel for how bad "perhaps bad" is by thinking about $m=0$ with $p=1$ (where solutions are medians) and $p=2$ (where the solution is the mean).

Comment: I attempted to summarize our discussion in an edit.

Comment: It's not as simple as $D_p \leq D_2$. Instead, $D_p$ is less than or equal to the $p$ norm of the error vector of the $2$-norm minimizer.

Comment: Right, I think I fixed it.

Comment: In some sense (1) is really only helpful in the case $m=0$, where it allows you to say that $|f_n-c| \leq |f_k-c| + |n-k|\omega$ for any constant $c$ and any $k$. For higher $m$, what matters is not so much the raw magnitude of the increments but how much they fluctuate.

Comment: I see your point, but $(1)$ does bound the fluctuation, no? For instance, if $\omega=0$ there cannot be any fluctuation.

Comment: I mean the fluctuation of the increments. For example if all the increments are the same then no matter how big they are, the $m=1$ approximation is already exact.

Comment: Condition (1) does bound the fluctuation of the increments as well, e.g. if $\omega=0$ there cannot be any fluctuation whatsoever. I think some bound dependent on $\omega$, $a$ and $b$ should exist. Perhaps considering a worst-case scenario function.